# Setting root-only permissions on /dev files and build binary

Tags: linux, bash, x86, setuid, msr

As part of a build process, I want to run the following two commands:

```
sudo chmod a+r /dev/cpu/*/msr
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio=ep ./bench
```

This sets the `/dev/cpu/*/msr` files exposed by the `msr` kernel module to world-readable, and sets additional permissions on the `./bench` binary (produced as part of the build) that it needs to actually read those files.

The problem is this requires root permissions, hence the `sudo`.

I'd like something like a setuid root script that does these two specific things, but [setuid root scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts) are not recommended and disabled on modern Linux.

What are my options here for a straightforward solution?

A solution which works only for the second line (the `setcap`) is also interesting, because I need this one to run *every* build, while the `chmod` only needs to run once per boot.

Answer (score 5):

Achieving the same thing via [`libcap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cap_get_file.3.html) is actually not that much code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
    cap_t c = cap_from_text("cap_sys_rawio=ep");
    int status = cap_set_file("./bench", c);
    cap_free(c);
    if (status)
        perror("attempt failed");
    return status != 0;
}
```

To compile this (on debian, you'll need to `sudo apt-get install libcap-dev`; on fedora, `sudo dnf install libcap-devel`):

```
$ gcc -o mkcap mkcap.c -lcap
```

If you just run it as is, it will fail since the program needs to have sufficient privilege to actually add the capability to `./bench`:

```
$ ./mkcap
attempt failed: Operation not permitted
```

So, you need to make it sufficiently capable itself:

```
$ sudo /sbin/setcap cap_setfcap=ep ./mkcap
$ ./mkcap
$ echo $?
0
```

- You might want to consider being more explicit with the path to the `"./bench"` binary since, depending on your environment, you might worry that someone could abuse `mkcap` to give `cap_sys_rawio` to some other program. Using a full pathname would be less ambiguous.
- You could also `chmod go-x ./mkcap` to limit who can run it.
- You could also consider using inheritable capabilities for all this:

```
basic $ sudo setcap cap_setfcap=ei ./mkcap
basic $ ./mkcap
attempt failed: Operation not permitted
basic $ sudo capsh --inh=cap_setfcap --user=$(whoami) --
enhanced $ ./mkcap
enhanced $ echo $?
0
```

In the `enhanced` (capsh shell) layer you are able to raise that capability on binaries that have their file inheritable bit set. This way, the default `basic` layer shells can't get any privilege out of `mkcap`. In all other ways, the `enhanced` shell layer is identical to a `basic` layer. For example, you can execute builds and pretty much do things as normal. (Use `exit` to leave the `enhanced` shell.)

There is a `pam_cap` module that can also add an inheritable bit to all shells of specific users at login etc time.

Comment: `cap_free` can set errno; perhaps better to check `status` and run `perror` right after `cap_set_file`.

Comment: In this specific case I think it is actually safe to not do this. If `cap_free()` is operating on a valid pointer, then it won't set `errno`. If it is operating something else, because the `cap_from_text()` function failed, then the printed 'perror()' will be more informative.

Answer (score 4):

You can build a simple C program to use in place of the shell script:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *const envp[] = {NULL};
    execle("/sbin/setcap", "setcap", "cap_sys_rawio=ep", "./bench", NULL, envp);
    perror("execle");
    return 1;
}
```

Notes:

- That's secure in that it ignores its environment (including PATH) and doesn't call the shell, but it can still be run from anywhere, so there's no guarantee of exactly what `./bench` is. You may want to hardcode the absolute path.
- You can use the same trick to run multiple commands, but then you have to get into `fork` and `wait`. (**Don't use `system`**, as this invokes a shell and defeats the purpose of disallowing setuid scripts!)
- Instead of calling the setcap binary, you could use [the `libcap` functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libcap.3.html) instead, but that would be a bit more complicated.
- You can use `glob` to expand `/dev/cpu/*/msr` like the shell does if you want to do the first part, and then `stat` and `chown` to avoid having to `exec`.

Comment: Thanks, the trick I was missing was an easy way to run shell commands from C. I knew you could write a C program, but I didn't want to painstakingly convert the shell script into system calls (which sometimes is very complicated, when the underlying process does a lot of work).

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, using libcap is a good option how to set capabilities. To access MSRs without sudo rights I suggest to use [msr-safe](https://github.com/LLNL/msr-safe). It has been implemented for Intel, however I have successfully tested it for AMD too. After loading a msr_safe kernel module, there will be a few new files. Instead of accessing msrs via `/dev/cpu/*/msr` you will use `/dev/cpu/*/msr_safe`. It will expose you registers listed in `/dev/cpu/msr_allowlist` (previously `msr_whitelist`). You may also control which bits of these registers will be writable, by a mask in the file.

Moreover it is possible to prepare a batch (`/dev/cpu/msr_batch`) - list of registers you will access repeatedly, so it will reduce overhead. This feature is implemented in [libmsr](https://github.com/LLNL/libmsr).